# Google Sheet Appscript - Clear Some Cell Values Based on Another Cells Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a script that based on a value in cell (value equal to 30 or more) located in column EQ to clear the contents of the cells located between columns EC to EH. The tab is "Form responses 1"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Cooper the below script definitely works, but now I would just need a small adjustment to it so that the IF statement lives between "29" and "50"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmBu8.png)

Comment: Can you link to a sheet or add a screen shot?

Comment: What script did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearSomeCellsBasedOnEQ () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  const sr = 1;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,147,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {
    if(e > 30) sh.getRange(i + sr,133,1,6).clearContent();
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper! This worked like a charm! Thank you very much! Sorry for the "noob" question but to have working on another tab called "Reading" and to have contents deleted from cells in columns P to R, what would need changing in the script you provided? Thank you once again!

Comment: Hi again Cooper! Just tried adapting the script and it's working! Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: in the If statement, would you be able to help to make it between 29 and 50? Thank you once again!